ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium for chat-bot
I am trying to use selenium to make a chat-bot for finance, but when i try to search something in a website's search tab using selenium I'm getting an error.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Initialize Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get('https://www.screener.in/home/')  

# Find the search input element by class name 
search_input = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'home-search')

# Interact with the input element (e.g., send keys)
search_input.send_keys('IOCL') 


time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 16
     13 search_input = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'home-search')
     15 # Interact with the input element (e.g., send keys)
---> 16 search_input.send_keys('IOCL')  # Example input value 'IOCL'
     18 #print(search_input)
     19 
     20 # Do other operations as needed...
     22 time.sleep(10)

File c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:231, in WebElement.send_keys(self, *value)
    228             remote_files.append(self._upload(file))
    229         value = "\n".join(remote_files)
--> 231 self._execute(
    232     Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {"text": "".join(keys_to_typing(value)), "value": keys_to_typing(value)}
    233 )

File c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:395, in WebElement._execute(self, command, params)
    393     params = {}
    394 params["id"] = self._id
--> 395 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:347, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    345 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
...
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF634391052]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6343818A4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFBBD291F88+24]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFBBED60B81+33]

Can someone look into it suggest me, what i should do to resolve this error

Did you use ChatGPT (or alternative AI) to write the code snippet above?

@BarrythePlatipus What difference does that make? ChatGPT is not banned from questions... only from answers.

I does make a difference @JeffC: AI generated content is banned on SoF in both questions and answers.

The problem is that your locator was finding a DIV. You can't type into a DIV. You need the INPUT inside that DIV.
<div class="home-search" style="margin-bottom:1.5rem">
            ^^^^^^^^^^^ your locator was finding this DIV
    <div class="has-addon left-addon dropdown-typeahead"> <i class="addon icon-search"></i>
        <input aria-label="Search for a company" type="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search for a company" class="u-full-width" autofocus="true" data-company-search="true" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
         ^^^^^ you need to find and type into this INPUT
        <ul class="dropdown-content"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

The code below successfully types 'IOCL' into the search box.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.home-search input[aria-label='Search for a company']"))).send_keys("IOCL")

